# My helm Chart does not works but the original yamls yes

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

This is my problem. Y have a yamls deployment for kubernetes that works fine. So, I am putting this yamls in a Helm Chart, but when I deploy de helm, I recived a 5032 error from Nginx:

```
 [error] 41#41: *1176907 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 79.144.175.25, server: envtest.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com, request: "POST /es/api/api/v1/terminals/login/123456789/monitor HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.63.136:80/v1/terminals/login/123456789/monitor", host: "envtest.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"
```

I am starter level, so I am so confused about the problem. I have compared my original files and the generated helm files and I dont see the error.
As my original yamls works, Im just going to copy here my helms files:

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "example.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    {{- include "example.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "example.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "example.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          {{- with .Values.env }}
          env:
            {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "example.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    {{- include "example.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    microservice: {{ .Values.microservice }}
    {{- include "example.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

I have a secret. yaml too:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secretname }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
type: Opaque
data:
  redis-connection-string: {{ .Values.redisconnectionstring | b64enc }}
  event-hub-connection-string:
    {{ .Values.eventhubconnectionstring | b64enc }}
  blob-storage-connection-string:
    {{ .Values.blobstorageconnectionstring | b64enc }}
  #(ingesters) sql
  sql-user-for-admin-user: {{ .Values.sqluserforadminuser | b64enc }}
  sql-user-for-admin-password:
    {{ .Values.sqluserforadminpassword | b64enc }}
```

By other hand, I still have out of the helm, in a convencional yaml, the ingress and the external service (as a parts of the set of yamls that works fine)

External Service

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: example-ingress
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: example.example-tpvs.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
    - port: 80
```

Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-logic
  namespace: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  labels:
    version: "0.1"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: envtest.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /es/example/api/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: example
              servicePort: 80
```

So, when I install the helm, I know the pod is up, and I can see in the pod logs that some backjobs are working, so Im almost sure that the problem are in the service of the heml... because this external and ingress are working when I deploy the originals yamls.

I hope someone could help me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is that I forgot the selectors and matchlabel in service and deployment